# System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement Insert in Access

Tags: asp.net

I think this should be an easy fix, but after two days, I just can't seem to find a solution.  I have a simple ASP.NET VS Express 2012 for Web and I'm trying insert a record into an access table using a FormView in Insert mode.

Here is my code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master"  AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="insert.aspx.cs" Inherits="mapbook_admin_insert" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="head" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" Runat="Server">
<asp:AccessDataSource ID="AccessDataSource1" runat="server" DataFile="~/mapbook/admin/mapbook.mdb" 
InsertCommand="INSERT INTO tblMaps 
    (txtFileName, txtMapName, txtCity, txtAddress, txtMapPage, txtGrid, txtZip, txtGateCode  
    VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)">
</asp:AccessDataSource>
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="AccessDataSource1" DefaultMode="Insert" Width="452px">
<InsertItemTemplate>
    PDF File Name:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFileNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("txtFileName") %>' />
    <br />
    Map Name:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMapNameTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("txtMapName") %>' />
    <br />
    City:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtCityTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("txtCity") %>' />
    <br />
    Address:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtAddressTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("txtAddress") %>' />
    <br />
    Map Page:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMapPageTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("txtMapPage") %>' />
    <br />
    Grid:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtGridTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("txtGrid") %>' />
    <br />
    Zip:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtZipTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("txtZip") %>' />
    <br />
    Gate Code:
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtGateCodeTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("txtGateCode") %>' />
    <br />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" />
    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
</InsertItemTemplate>
</asp:FormView>
</asp:Content>
```

The error I get is "System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: Syntax error in INSERT INTO statement." I'm inserting into an Access database.

Thank you all in advanced.

Comment: You're missing a closing bracket at the end of the list of column names: `..., txtGateCode VALUES (...` - is that just a typo in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Richard Deeming, he noticed my missing ')' in the INSERT command. It's now working.